# Foundation 5 : Columns order issue in responsive layout (demonstration included)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

This is my first question here, i hope that i can find an answer/fix to my problem.

I'm actually using Foundation as a framework for my mobile-first e-commerce website, i wonder how can i make this order of rows : https://cloudup.com/cKSc66C6Mwt

Part 1 is actually a title of the product.
Part 2 is the slider (Orbit Slider) with a thumbnail carousel.
Par 3 is the description of the product.

I looked in Foundation's documentation and forum for answers, the single described solution was making this happen using media queries but it wasn't successful, so i'm wondering if there is any alternative solution.

Thank you

**EDIT :**

There is something called "Source Ordering" in foundation 5, i think it can be a good solution for similar problems but not mine.

This solution (bellow) worked for me, but i'm still looking for something better. It's based on creating two divs with the same id and the same title (it's not good to create two divs with the same id, i know..) and use the options : hide-for-small and show-for-small

Check this out :

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="row" style="padding:10px;">
        <div class="large-4 show-for-small columns" id="title"></div>
        <div class="large-4 columns" id="slider"></div>
        <div class="large-8 hide-for-small columns" id="title"></div>
        <div class="large-8 columns" id="description"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).foundation();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the CSS :

```
 #title { position: relative;
         background-color: #755172;
         height: 50px;
}

#slider { position: relative;
          background-color: #aa6ca5;
          height: 250px;    
}

#description { position: relative;
               background-color: #d8afd5;
               height: 200px;   
}
```

Any different solution is welcome

Comment: To get help, you would need to try something and paste the code here.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row" style="padding:10px;">
    <div class="small-12 large-6 columns">      
        <div class="small-12 columns hide-for-small-only" id="slider">2</div>
        <div class="small-12 show-for-small-only columns" id="title">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="small-12 large-6 columns">
        <div class="small-12 hide-for-small-only columns" id="title">1</div>
        <div class="small-12 show-for-small-only columns" id="title">2</div>
        <div class="small-12 columns" id="description">3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the code. Another good option is to use the flexbox technique. A really good example described [here.](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

But remember, that flexbox is not fully supported by IE starting from 10, Firefox till 28, etc.

Comment: Thank you, the only thing missed here is the id="slider" instead of id="title" in line 8. 

I think flexbox is a good way though, but my users insights show me that i'm still stuck with IE. So i'm just going to use the hide/show option.

Thanks again